# Including multiple layouts inside ToolBar element

Tags: android, layout

Is it possible to include multiple layout files inside toolbar element like below? My code below displaying only the first layout included.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/editor_app_bar_height"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

        <include layout="@layout/formula_layout"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Yes, we can add multiple layouts in the Toolbar.

Comment: @MavyaSoni i could not.. the toolbar_layout and formula_layout has LinearLayout as its root element. My app bar displays only the toolbar_layout

Comment: So You should give one parent layout for it Like Toolbar -> LinearLayout/FrameLayout/...... -> include tag.

Comment: @MavyaSoni that increases the depth of my view hierarchy. Its the very reason i made separate layouts.

Comment: In your case, include take your parent layout reference as toolbar. So that toolbar is not linear or a relative reference. So you have to add one parent layout for it.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, <include> Tag refere as a parent layout in your code you have toolbar. So that <include> tag refere parent layout is Toolbar.

Comment: @mavyaSoni  oh okay. So I should put our <include> tags inside a liner layout/frame layout, am I right?

Comment: Yes, You are right